# Determine columns which have a value in any row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 14 million records. For a given set (ie: where PartId = 13) I wish to form a list of all columns which have a value greater than 0 in any record. There are 60 columns of interest for purposes of this query. Note that the columns are nullable.

Is there a faster way to do it than the below?

```
select
        -- this sample uses 3 columns, but my actual table does this same thing
        -- for 60 columns

        stuff( -- remove the leading space and comma
            case when 0 = max(isnull(col_1, 0)) then '' else ', col_1' end + 
            case when 0 = max(isnull(col_2, 0)) then '' else ', col_2' end + 
            case when 0 = max(isnull(col_3, 0)) then '' else ', col_3' end,
            1, 2, ''
        )
from    Applications
where   PartId = 13
```

This query returns exactly what I want. For a given part with 800,000 grouped records this SQL runs on my machine in less than 5 seconds, which is pretty good I thought.

The result of this will be the column list to be used in a select statement (business logic dictates that every row will have at least 1 column with a value greater than 0).

I tried with a query with 60 sub-queries each using EXISTS, but that was considerably slower.

I also tried with SUM:

```
case when 0 = (sum(case when isnull(col_1, 0) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)) then '' else ', col_1' end +
case when 0 = (sum(case when isnull(col_2, 0) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)) then '' else ', col_2' end
```

Which is about the same speed as the MAX variation above.

The reason for the query is that a customer wants a report where we show only columns which have a value in any row for each part. I'm displaying the data with jqGrid (and allowing an XLSX download). With jqGrid I don't want to remove empty columns on a page by page basis because that would mean not all pages would have the same columns; which would mean the sorting/filtering possibilities would vary page by page.

Edit 1

Though I think I would get rid of the ISNULL by doing:

```
case when max(col_1) > 0 then ', col_1' else '' end
```

Comment: Since you code works well, what is your question here?

Comment: @Sami "Is there a faster way to do it than this"

Comment: Right @TabAlleman that's true.

Comment: More of a JQWidgets guy myself, but can't your grid be be defined as the full 60 columns, and then on the client side, you hide the "empty" columns?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Technically I could could, sure, but that's not what the client requested. Of course page to page it's not very aesthetically appealing if the table size changes (page 1 might hide no columns, page 2 might have 50 columns hidden, etc)

Comment: Ah, your paging... You're right, that would be ugly and cumbersome.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti 800,000 records (see original post) not-paged is a tad slow to load in IE ;) In fact, 100 rows is slow to load in IE (compared to Chrome) heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that "might" be more readable and manageable is to Unpivot the Data so that instead of checking 60 columns you just check 1 column.
This would be of more use if your check column logic is more complex as it avoids repeating it 60 times.

You would add a CROSS APPLY to your select

```
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('col_1', col_1), 
                    ('col_2', col_2) 
                    etc
             ) unpiv (col_name, col_val)
```

The idea then is you can write your check once and it is applied to all the relevant columns. 
In your case it would be a simple where clause

```
WHERE col_val > 0
```

Comment: john McTighe - Your method takes 38 seconds the first time it's executed (mine took 7s the first run), BUT your method takes < 1 second every execution after the first whereas mine takes 3s on every execution after the first.

Comment: The First run builds the execution plan so that's normally a bit slower. 38 secs is very slow though. This could be mitigated by wrapping it in a stored proc. Also the subsequent runs might be using Cached Data which would invalidate the quick timings. I wasn't actually expecting it to be quicker - just more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Correction, I did further testing, and when I `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE; CHECKPOINT; DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;` both of our queries are about identical times. But yes, yours is easier to read, thank you. When I run these commands, the first run of your query is reliably 9 seconds (and 2 seconds for each run thereafter). I'm not sure why it was 38 seconds earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've done it in your first code snippet is exactly the way I would do it.